# PHP, Triming leading 0s problem

Tags: php, trim

So here is the problem
I am getting a Hex number from a input filed
it could looks something like this
FFFF, 000CA3, blah blah blah
while trim these down is easy just with
$var = ltrim('0',$var);

My problem is when the user type in '0000' and such
it trims the whole string to nothing.
I could certainly do a if statement on that after the trim result check string become null and add a 0 if it does.
but is there any other neat trick out there can solve this like in one statement?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one I can think of:

```
$var = dechex(hexdec($var));
```

[`hexdec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php) converts strings to actual numeric values, so any insignificant zeroes are just that — insignificant. [`dechex()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php) converts them back to strings once the zeroes are dropped.

If you require uppercase hex A-F digits for some strange reason, just tack on a `strtoupper()` call as `dechex()` produces hex digits in lowercase:

```
$var = strtoupper(dechex(hexdec($var)));
```